# Java Database instantly disconnect

Tags: java, sql, database, sqlite, connection

I try to edit and read out of my database and I always get a connection but I'm not able to insert or select anything from the database because it tells me the connection is already closed again. So the methods don't work. I don't understand why.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class Test {

    public static Connection connect() {
        Connection conn = null;
        String url = "jdbc:sqlite:C:/Users/eichw/Desktop/test.db";

        try {

            // create a connection to the database
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

            System.out.println("Connection to SQLite has been established.");

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                if (conn != null) {
                    conn.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }      
        return conn;
    }

   public void selectAll(){
        String sql = "SELECT KNr, KName, KFirma, KMail FROM test";

        try (Connection conn = this.connect();
             Statement stmt  = conn.createStatement();
             ResultSet rs    = stmt.executeQuery(sql)){

            // loop through the result set
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getInt("KNr") +  "\t" + 
                                   rs.getString("KName") + "\t" +
                                   rs.getDouble("KFirma"));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test app = new Test();
       app.selectAll();

    }
}
```

Comment: Your `connect()` method closes the connection in the `finally` block, so it returns an already closed connection .The `finally` always gets executed, even though you don't get any exceptions.

Comment: Thank you man ... i think i just was blind

Answer (score 1):

As @Berger said on the comments, your connect() method is opening the connection, but then it's also closing it right after, in the finally block.

Then you return the connection object already closed to the selectAll() method. It then tries to create a Statement and so on with a connection that is already closed.

What you need to do is to open the connection, return it, use it and only after it's used you should close it.